# Table: "\multicolumn" Unwanted Border (Vertical Rule)

Tags: tables

- Maybe this is a stupid question.
- The simple table uses `\multicolumn`.
- But there is an unwanted vertical line (green) although `{c}` is used (without `|`).
- How to get rid of the vertical line (green)?

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Yada Yada Yada}
\begin{tabular}{|lrrr|r|c|lrrr|r|}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11 \\
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11 \\
\multicolumn{5}{c}{5 Columns \cellcolor{red}}   & 1 Column  &  \multicolumn{5}{c}{5 Columns \cellcolor{red}}   \\ \cline{1-5} \cline{7-11}
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11 \\
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What about `\newcolumntype{?}{!{\color{red}\vrule width \arrayrulewidth}}` in combination with `\multicolumn{5}{c}{5 Columns \cellcolor{red}}   & \multicolumn{1}{c?}{1 Column}  &  \multicolumn{5}{c}{5 Columns \cellcolor{red}}`?

Comment: @leandriisThanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is set as part of the middle `1 Column`. You can remove it with `\multicolumn{1}{c}` and reinsert the appropriate column gap:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{2pt}

\begin{tabular}{ | l r r r | r | c | l r r r | r | }
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{\cellcolor{red}5 Columns} & 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{1 Column} & 
    \multicolumn{5}{@{\hspace{\dimexpr\arraycolsep-.5\arrayrulewidth}}c}{\cellcolor{red}5 Columns} \\
  \cline{1-5} \cline{7-11}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @Werner!

Comment: What is the reason for the complicated looking second multicolumn line?